# Binary subtraction using the direct way

Tags: binary, computer-science

Why is `01101.101 - 11011.110` equal to `1110.001` and not `110001.111` whereas `10101.101 - 01011.110` is equal to `1001.111`. The numbers after the decimal are the same but the first number gets me `0.001` yet second number is equal to `0.111`.
[image]

Comment: the left operation doesn't seem to make sense even taking the numbers as signed (from 109 and 222 to make 113, forget about the dot it doesn't matter for now). Where are these coming from? The right one matches with Windows calculator.

Comment: The two results are equivalent, if you convert the first one to two's complement by flipping all the bits and adding 1: `...001110.001 --flip--> ...110001.110 --add1--> ...110001.111`.